# Filter data From vapor client get

Tags: swift, get, client, vapor, server-side-swift

i'm using vapor's client to fetch a get request.

```
func sendGetRequest(req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
    let client = try req.make(FoundationClient.self)
    return client.get("http://example.vapor.codes/json", headers: ["Accept-Language" : "ar"])
        .map(to: Response.self, { clientResponse in
        let response = req.makeResponse()
        response.http.status = clientResponse.http.status
        response.http.body = clientResponse.http.body
        return response
    })
}
```

this returns all the json data , i want to filter it to just return 2 attributes, for example in this case (dict,number)

i've created a model for the data

```
struct ExampleData: Codable {
  //  var array : [Int]
    var dict : [String : String]
    var number : Int
 //   var string : String
}
```

the function expects me to return a Future< Response>, but if i change it to  Future< ExampleData> and set the mapping to .map(to: ExampleData.self ..)

i get

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Response' to return type
>   'TodoController.ExampleData'

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you still returning the `Response` object you created inside of your `.map(to: ExampleData.self...`? Or did you change that to return an `ExampleData` struct?

Comment: @ssrobbi the return is of type ExampleData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out

```
func sendGetRequest(req: Request) throws -> Future<ExampleData> {
    let client = try req.make(Client.self)
    let ans =  client.get("http://example.vapor.codes/json", headers: ["Accept-Language" : "ar"]).flatMap { exampleResponse in
        return try exampleResponse.content.decode(ExampleData.self)
    }

    return ans
}
```